# Virtualmin configuration for a shared webhosting server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-hosting, webmin, virtualmin

I'm trying to build a web hosting server on Google Cloud Platform. Managed to install the LAMP stack and Virtualmin & Webmin on that. My purpose is to setup the server to host 4 websites with different domain names.
I have created child nameservers under my main domain to point to this server, and that is propagating OK.
What configuration do I need to apply in the Virtualmin so that it could accept requests coming from different domain names?

Comment: Firstly server configuration is off topic on Stack Overflow. Also you should ask an actual question, not ask if someone could help. Nobody can know if they can if they don't know the problem. But please find a more suitable place for the question first.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, wonder if could suggest a right forum, please. Thank you